# Calling a function from StringBuilder(vb.net)

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net

How can I call a function in javascript from the `stringBuilder` in VB.Net?

Code:

```
oSB.Append("<table id= '" + table_id + "' class='sortable' ><thead><tr><th           class=border onclick='sort()'>" + "Name" + "</th><th class=border>" + "Duration" + "</th><th class=border>" + "State" + "</th><th class=border>" + "Party" + "</th><th class=border>" + "Year" + "</th></tr></thead>")
```

Is this a correct method?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the outdated `onclick` attribute, you should assign you handlers via javascript/jQuery. This makes for a better separation of concerns.

First of all remove the `onclick="sort()"` from your code, and add this jQuery code to the page:

```
$(".sortable th:first").click(function() {
    // do something...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the inline `onclick` event.. and use jquery `click` event instead

```
$(".sortable th:first").click(function() {
   // do your stuff
});
```